# Bootstrap Right Align Column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having trouble with Bootstrap Columns.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xtbq64qr/)

**Code**

```css
.index_heading {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}

.header_index {
}

.border {
    border:1px solid red;
    margin-right:100px;
}
.login {
    margin-top:3%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row index_heading">
  <div class="col-md-6 border pull-right">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
      <div class="login">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username">
        </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password"><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="login" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want is for the login `button` to be next to the right horizontal line.

I have tried `pull-right` and `text-right` but neither of them work.

Any solutions would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can you [column ordering](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#example-column-ordering) to move columns around.

So for you log in column you could use

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-push-4">
```

Which will move that div over four columns from its normal place.